# Generate openapi specification for spring boot data rest with correct method names

Tags: java, spring-data, openapi, openapi-generator

I generate open API specification from my spring boot data rest endpoints. That's working but the generated method names in the openapi.yaml are unequal to the method names in the repository interface.

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <apiDocsUrl>http://dev-container:8081/v3/api-docs.yaml</apiDocsUrl>
        <outputFileName>openapi.yaml</outputFileName>
        <outputDir>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDir>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

UserRepository.java => Spring JpaRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    public Iterable<User> findByTestname(@Param("n") String n);
}
```

The Result in my openapi.yaml is:

```
  /users/search/findByTestname:
    get:
      tags:
      - user-search-controller
      operationId: executeSearch-user-get
      parameters:
      - name: "n"
        in: query
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/hal+json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/CollectionModelEntityModelUser'
        "404":
          description: Not Found
```

If I add the @Operation annotation to the method then the name will be generated correct.

UserRepository.java with annotation:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    @Operation(operationId = "findByTestname")
    public Iterable<User> findByTestname(@Param("n") String n);
}
```

And the result looks correct.

```
  /users/search/findByTestname:
    get:
      tags:
      - user-search-controller
      operationId: findByTestname
      parameters:
```

**Question:** It is possible to configure the generator to use the correct method name without annotating it? I just want to configure it and not override or implement something.

Comment: I didn't think JPA had any association with the REST API endpoints. How would a generator know what your code looks like before it was written?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't understand your comment. I think the problem is openapi generator and the spring boot data rest repositories. Everything is generated fine but the method names.

Comment: And it appears the generator requires annotations to have the correct output. It won't otherwise parse the interface function names